# How do I get a white border in a figure that has been plotted in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, border

I have written the following code that calculates the orientation of a blob using eigenvalues. When the orientation is determined, the function "straighten_up" straightens the blob out.

The only thing I'm missing to be fully satisfied, is a 1px white border in the second output figure between the black area and the green area. How can I do this?

I'm using a mask image as input:

[image: input image]

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('input_image.png',100)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,0,255) #searching for a border

# compute the orientation of a blob
img = edges 
y, x = np.nonzero(img) # Find the index of the white pixels

x = x - np.mean(x) #The average of an array of elements
y = y - np.mean(y)
coords = np.vstack([x, y])

cov = np.cov(coords) #determine covariance matrix 
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(cov) #eigenvectors

sort_indices = np.argsort(evals)[::-1] #Sort Eigenvalues in decreasing order
x_v1, y_v1 = evecs[:, sort_indices[0]]  
x_v2, y_v2 = evecs[:, sort_indices[1]]

scale = 30
plt.plot([x_v1*-scale*2, x_v1*scale*2], #plot to show the eigenvectors
         [y_v1*-scale*2, y_v1*scale*2], color='red')
plt.plot([x_v2*-scale, x_v2*scale],
         [y_v2*-scale, y_v2*scale], color='blue')
plt.plot(x, y, 'k.')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  
plt.show()

def straighten_up(x_v1,y_v1,coords):
    theta = np.arctan((x_v1)/(y_v1))
    rotation_mat =np.matrix([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])
    transformed_mat = rotation_mat*coords

    x_transformed, y_transformed = transformed_mat.A

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) # nrows, ncols, index
    ax.set_facecolor((1.0, 0.47, 0.42))

    plt.plot(x_transformed,y_transformed,"black")

straighten_up(x_v1,y_v1,coords)
plt.show()
```

with output:

[image: output images]

Comment: You are right I will edit my post.

Comment: The text "orientatie berekenen van een blob figuur" you better add as part of an introduction to your question.

Comment: But my problem isn't essentially my code I want to achieve something that is not yet coded, I just put my code to give a visual.

Comment: I have written a short intro on your request and put my question in the beginning

Comment: By the way, never use arctan to get a rotation angle. Always use [arctan2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) to avoid division by zero, to avoid instability near to zero, and to get the full 360 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Your `x_transformed` and `y_transformed` are the x and y coordinates of the rotated border. So you can draw them e.g. with `plt.scatter`. This draws dots (the third parameter is the size) on these x,y positions. Use `zorder` to make sure the scatter dots are not hidden by the previous parts of the plot.

Following code does just that:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) # nrows, ncols, index
    ax.set_facecolor('fuchsia')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.plot(x_transformed, y_transformed, c="lime")
    plt.scatter(x_transformed, y_transformed, 1, c="white", zorder=3)
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot with added white border]

As you notice, there is another problem: the plot of the filled figure isn't similar to your input image. What is happening, is that plot draws lines`(x[0],y[0])` to `(x[1],y[1])` to `(x[2],y[2])` etc.. As your x and y are only the border points, not ordered as a polygon, it is more complicated to get a correctly filled polygon. For a random input image, you can have many borders, that can form polygons with holes and islands and which can touch the image borders.

To properly get the interior points, you might get `y, x = np.nonzero(img)` from the original image (instead of only the edges), then do the same shift subtracting the mean of the edges, and use the same transformation matrix.

Comment: This is a start of what I want, thank you for the effort!

Comment: If this answers your question, consider marking it as the accepted answer. If you have other questions, you could create a new post.

Comment: To get the interior points, you might get `y, x = np.nonzero(img)` from the original image (instead of only the edges), then do the same shift subtracting the mean of the edges, and use the same transformation matrix.